# How to get the vector representation of a word using a trained SVD model

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svd, lsa

I have trained (fit and transform) a SVD model using 400 documents as part of my effort to build a LSA model. Here is my code:

```
tfidf_vectorizer = sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer(stop_words='english', use_idf=True, smooth_idf=True)
svd_model = TruncatedSVD(n_components=100, n_iter=10)
lsa_pipeline = Pipeline([('tfidf', tfidf_vectorizer), ('svd', svd_model)])
lsa_model = lsa_pipeline.fit_transform(all_docs)
```

Now, I want to measure the similarity of two sentences (whether from the same document collection or totally new) and I need to transform these two sentences into vectors. I want to do the transformation in my own way and I need to have the vector of each word in sentence.

How can I find the vector of a word using the **lsa_model** that I already trained?

And, more broadly speaking, does it make sense to build a LSA model using a collection of documents and then use the same model for measuring the similarity of some sentences from the same document collection?

Comment: You'll want to look at `lsa_model.components_`. Also, hi from DC. :-)

Comment: @erip Hi from DC bud! I think lsa_model is an array and it does not have an attribute named "components_"

Comment: Oh, I misread! I thought you had `fit` the model, not `fit_transform`.

Answer (score 2):

You are almost there, you just need to transform the sentences into vectors

```
sentence_vector = lsa_pipeline.transform(sentence)
```

Then find the distance between the sentence vector and the document matrix [using any metric of your choice](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise_distances.html)

```
from sklearn.metrics import pairwise_distances
dist_per_doc_matrix = pairwise_distances(sentence_vector,lsa_model, metric= 'euclidean')
```

Similarly you can take [cosine similarity](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.cosine_similarity.html#sklearn.metrics.pairwise.cosine_similarity) of two sentence vectors as well.

References

- [LSA for text classification](http://mccormickml.com/2016/03/25/lsa-for-text-classification-tutorial/)
- [NLP using scikit-learn](https://towardsdatascience.com/machine-learning-nlp-text-classification-using-scikit-learn-python-and-nltk-c52b92a7c73a)

Comment: Thanks Mohammed. This answer technically solved my problem but it may not be the exact answer to the question. I am still trying to find the vector of each word separately. Sometimes you may want to convert a sentence to vector in a different way.

Comment: Your welcome :) But if you want to use the same model for prediction you would want to change the sentences in the same way else the result would be wrong. I mean if you don't change the word into vectors the same way you did while creating the model, it would be algorithmically wrong. I think word2vec, glove, fasttext might be better suited for this job than LSA if you want to go ahead with the idea you have. If this answer helped you out, feel free to upvote or mark it as the correct one :)